# "TCHAR cFileName[MAX_PATH];" - mistake in the MSDN library?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> cFileName 
>           The name of the file.

The value of `MAX_PATH` is <s>the same as</s>  almost the same as `_MAX_FNAME`, but using the first is misleading in this case. Anyway, if they meant the full path with name, should it be `cFileName[MAX_PATH+_MAX_FNAME];`? What was the purpose of using `MAX_PATH`?

Comment: `MAX_PATH` is not the same as `_MAX_FNAME`.  `MAX_PATH` is 260, `_MAX_FNAME` is 256.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MAX_PATH` constant represents the maximum length of an *entire* path, including the file name and the extension. It is irrelevant whether it is a relative path, a fully-qualified path, or even just a file name; they all have the same maximum length.

Thus, you would never see `MAX_PATH + _MAX_FNAME` because that would exceed the maximum length allowed for a path.

You'll find pretty much everything you ever wanted to know about paths in Win32 in [this article](http://MSDN.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx). Note that some APIs (these will generally be called out explicitly in the docs ) accept long path names, indicated with a special prefix, which are not subject to the limitations of `MAX_PATH`.

The function signature is correct in this case. Sometimes, though, there are snippets of sample code on MSDN that accompany the docs, and this sample code ranges anywhere from stylistically curious to an utter abomination. It's always worth using a good healthy dose of common sense when trying to adapt sample code you find.

Answer (score 2):

There's no mistake here. In Windows APIs that are subject to limits on length, the maximum length of a name is (usually) `MAX_PATH`. It doesn't matter whether the name is a fully specified absolute path, a relative path, or just a file name, the length limit is still `MAX_PATH`.

It may well be that the underlying file system has different limits. It's perfectly plausible that the native file system limit could be less than 260. But if the API declares a limit of 260 characters, then that's the limit when using that particular API.

If ever you think that the MSDN library is incorrect, it's easy enough to check. Take a look at the definition in the Windows header file and compare it with that given in the MSDN library. Invariably you will find that the MSDN library is accurate.